# Angular Material Autocomplete observable fires additional time after selecting dropdown option

Tags: angular, angular-material, observable

Anytime I select an option from Material Autocomplete, it makes an additional HTTP GET call to the server. The desired result of selecting a dropdown option should just be to populate the input.

The dropdown options are retrieved dynamically from the server.

**HTML**:

```
<form class="example-form">
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
      <input type="text" placeholder="search item" aria-label="Item1" matInput [formControl]="searchTerm" [matAutocomplete]="auto1">
      <mat-autocomplete #auto1="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let item of searchResult" [value]="item.Id">
          {{ item.Name }}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
  </form>
```

**TypeScript**:

```
    searchTerm : FormControl = new FormControl();

    searchResult = [];
    constructor(private service: AppService){
      this.searchTerm.valueChanges
          .debounceTime(400) 
          .subscribe(data => {
              this.service.search_word(data).subscribe(response =>{
                  this.searchResult = response
              })
```

Everything else works fine. The only issue is the unexpected extra call to the server when the autocomplete option is selected.

QUICK UPDATE: No answer has totally solved this yet. However, I have narrowed this down to possibly be a problem with displayWith.

Comment: Why is it unexpected? It changes the value doesn't it?

Comment: You have subscribed to `valueChanges`. Am I wrong that selecting the option changes the value of the text field? You might want to add `.distinctUntilChanged()`.

Comment: I'm getting: [ts] Property 'distinctUntilChanged' does not exist on type 'FormControl'.

Comment: add `import 'rxjs/add/operators/distinctUntilChanged';`. Also, it needs to be applied like `valueChanges.distinctUntilChanged()`

Comment: Actually, this didn't work. I'm getting the same functionality as before.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160665/discussion-between-aluan-haddad-and-chemdream).

Comment: In 2020 - Angular version 10 - this problem is still there and no proper solution to be found...

Answer (score 4):

Your issue is occurring because the dropdown selection changes the value of the `searchTerm` form control; thus emitting an event for the `valueChanges` observable on that form control.

There are a few ways to build some logic into your `valueChanges` observable on the form control in order to ignore this unwanted Http GET request.

**Naive solution**

The naive solution is to store the dropdown option selection value and skip the observable logic if the `selectionValue === searchTerm.value`.

```
var optionSelection; // set this value on selection of a dropdown option
this.searchTerm.valueChanges
  .debounceTime(400) 
  .subscribe(data => {
    if (optionSelection !== searchTerm.value) {
      this.service.search_word(data).subscribe(response =>{
        this.searchResult = response
      })
    }
  })
```

**Better Solution**

The FormControl class has a `setValue` function, which has an optional parameter to specify whether or not to emit an event to the `valueChanges` observable.

```
setValue(value: any, options: {
    onlySelf?: boolean;
    emitEvent?: boolean;
    emitModelToViewChange?: boolean;
    emitViewToModelChange?: boolean;
} = {}): void
```

By changing your dropdown option selection to set the searchTerm form control value with `setValue`, you can pass the optional `emitEvent: false` parameter and stop this additional observable event from emitting.

```
searchTerm.setValue(dropdownValue, { emitEvent: false });
```

> If emitEvent is false, this change will cause a valueChanges event on the FormControl to not be emitted. This defaults to true (as it falls through to updateValueAndValidity).

Comment: When I add this, I'm getting: [ts] Cannot find name 'dropdownValue' ... Do I need to change dropdownValue to something?

Comment: Yes, it should be the value of your drop down option selection. Perhaps searchResult[i].value

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I fully understand (new to Angular). Where would I put the setValue code? Would it replace my ValueChanges code?

Comment: Thanks for this.  It helped me to realize that formgroup.patchValue also has this emitEvent flag, which solved my issue.  (I'm not using material, but had a similar problem)

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the amount of event that are tiggered there are two... I already made a bug for it's but it's how it supposed to work. Hope this will help.

This is my solution:

Html:

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let item of searchResult" [value]="item.Id" (onSelectionChange)="onSelectionChange($event, item.Id)"> // or item
```

In your component:

```
private onSelectionChange(_event: any, _id: any) {
  if (_event.isUserInput === true) { // there are two events one with true and one with false;
    this.service.search_word(_id).subscribe(response =>{
         this.searchResult = response
    })
}
```

Comment: Like I said this is how they designed it.
https://github.com/angular/components/issues/7851
Also check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53916279/7672014

Answer (score 1):

you can use `(keyup)="onKeyUp($event)"` in your input text and you can use it like this

```
onKeyUp(event: any) {
   this.service.search_word(event.target.value).subscribe(response =>{
                  this.searchResult = response
              })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As of Angular Material version 7.2.0 you have a new [EventEmitter](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/api) called 'optionSelected', for MatAutocomplete

So your HTML would be something like this:

```
<mat-autocomplete (optionSelected)="optionSelected($event)" #auto1="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let item of searchResult" [value]="item.Id">
      {{ item.Name }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
```

And your .ts:

```
private optionSelected(event) {
  console.log(event)
}
```

And you would handle it inside of `optionSelected()` method.

Give it a try as I don't have all your code. And let me know if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is tricky way, Set option value as **object** instead of **string**, then when the input changed you can determine if that from typing or selecting.

```
<!-- Template -->
<mat-option *ngFor="let item of searchResult" [value]="item">

// Component
this.searchTerm.valueChanges.subscribe(modelValue => {
  if (typeof modelValue === 'string') {
    this.searchUser.next(modelValue.toString());
  } else {
    this.searchTerm.setValue(modelValue.Id, {
      emitEvent: false
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `keyup` instead of `valueChanges`. Below is how I solved the same issue. Please keep in mind, this example is here to display my use case of keyup with `mat-autocomplete`.

```
import { ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';
import { debounceTime, tap, switchMap, map, filter, distinctUntilChanged } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Add `mat-autocomplete` html, note this also includes a loading spinner during http calls on remote but can be removed.

```
 <mat-form-field>
   <input matInput #searchInput placeholder="" [matAutocomplete]="auto">             
   <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
    <mat-option *ngIf="isLoading">
     <mat-spinner diameter="50"></mat-spinner>
    </mat-option>
    <ng-container *ngIf="!isLoading">
     <mat-option *ngFor="let data of filteredData | async" [value]="data.modelValue">
      <span>{{ data.modelValue }}</span>
     </mat-option>
    </ng-container>
   </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
```

Add the following to your controller.

```
isLoading: boolean;
@ViewChild('searchInput') searchInput: ElementRef;
filteredData: searchModel[] = [];
```

Setup the `keyup` event listener.

```
fromEvent(this.searchInput.nativeElement, 'keyup').pipe(
  map((event: any) => {
    return event.target.value; // Map search input value
  }),
  filter(res => res.length > 3), // If character length greater then 3
  debounceTime(500),
  distinctUntilChanged(), // If previous search is different from current
  tap((val) => {
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.filteredData = [];
  }),
  switchMap(value =>
    this.service.search(value).pipe(
      finalize(() => this.isLoading = false)
    )

  )
).subscribe(data => {
  this.filteredData = data;
});
```